# How to run gtk.Builder.connect_signals multiple times?

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk, glade

This is a follow-up question [to this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487677/).

I am trying to extend gtk.Builder but I found out that **once the builder is instantiated one can only call the [connect_signals](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkbuilder.html#method-gtkbuilder--connect-signals) method once**: if called more than once, any call after the second will return `None` (which would mean: all signals have been connected, which is a blatant lie!).

The problem is that in my design I would need to pass around the builder instance to various modules (each of them has some of the handlers for managing the GUI), but this way, I can't.

I tried to see if I could **understand how/where gtk.Builder stores the handler names that assigned withing the Glade GUI**, in order to write my own method to overcome this limitation, but after more than an hour of console experiments I still haven't understand where this information is stored.

Any help or pointer is highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `connect_signals` only works once is an [old](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=554301) but undocumented limitation of the GtkBuilder C code. Especially from Python there is no way to access its internals to remedy that.

Instead of the builder you could pass around a dictionary. After everyone added their handlers you call `connect_signals` with it.

Comment: Indeed I reached the same conclusion but had not time to publish the answer. +1 and accepted, thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

i think if you want to call connect_signals multiple times you must disconnect inbetween, kindof like

```
x = self.menu.connect('activate', self.func1)
self.menu.disconnect(x)
x = self.menu.connect('activate', self.func2)
```

Comment: `self.menu.connect` is not a `gtk.Builder` method. Also, it doesn't connect self to a callback, but a GUI signals to a specified class handlers.